# Rails 4: encrypt/decrypt email and store in DB

Tags: email, encryption, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

Passwords are hashed with a salt and are thus "secure" (relatively speaking) by default using has_secure_password in Rails 4.  But what I want to do is encrypt the email at rest in the DB so if the database is compromised somehow the emails aren't just in plaintext.

I've looked at just writing my own encrypt/decrypt functions, but that's dangerous.  I've looked at attr_encrypted (and have used it before) but it's not really compatible with the new `Model.find_by(key: value)` syntax that Rails 4+ pushes, and I don't want to create a hacked fix.

Is there anything out there already that will allow me to easily encrypt an attribute in the DB at rest and then decrypt it when I need to find it?  I can't use hashes because I need the decrypted value to display and send emails to later.

I've googled for a while but can't seem to find anything like this.  Surely encrypt/decrypt is something very basic that's been put into a convenient gem that's been reviewed by the community?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the [attr_encrypted](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted) gem?

Comment: I have looked at the `attr_encrypted` gem.  I have used it very successfully in previous versions of rails (before 4+) but with the latest Rails 4+ versions I ran into some issues with `attr_encrypted` and the preferred syntax by Rails.  Since I didn't want to implement a "hack" solution, I decided to either find another solution or wait until this gem is updated.  This kind of security is too important to me to use a non-standard/tested solution.  Thanks for the recommendation though!